# Remote SQL Server connection with SSMS

Tags: sql-server, connection, ssms

I have the SQL Server on my job, and I need to connect in this server from home using the SQL Server Management Studio, how can I do this?

I already do the connection from another computer in the same network, but i don't know how do this connection from an external network.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

There's 2 ways and both require VPN:

1) Connect to your work terminal server where you have SSMS already installed

2) Your local machine SSMS will automatically identify your work network once you click Connect.

I work remotely 2x per week and I use both ways.

Comment: @Fritsch, both of these require your company's network administrator's agreement. They should already have a VPN and policies around it established, make sure you're in compliance. You should **not** be connecting from home with your personal computer, only use company equipment.